# how to rotate the HSSFShapeTypes.ThickArrow

Tags: java, apache-poi

```
HSSFSimpleShape p3 = patriarch.createSimpleShape(anchor);
p3.setShapeType(HSSFShapeTypes.ThickArrow);
```

I create a shape in my **excel** by **apache poi**, how to rotate the `ThickArrow`?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First: What your screenshot shows is not a `HSSFShapeTypes.ThickArrow` but a `HSSFShapeTypes.HomePlate`.

Second: The answer to your question is simply using [HSSFShape.setFlipHorizontal](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFShape.html#setFlipHorizontal-boolean-). The default direction of shapes is left to right. So if one needs the same shape to left, it must be flipped horizontally. So

```
p3.setFlipHorizontal(true);
```

should do the trick.

To be a better reference for other readers too, here is a complete example which works using binary `BIFF` `HSSF` file system as well as using `Office Open XML`XSSF` file system:

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

class CreateExcelThickArrowShape {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

  //Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./CreateExcelShapes.xlsx";
  Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./CreateExcelShapes.xls";

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");

  CreationHelper helper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
  Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

  //Anchor1
  //This determines the size of the shape to be from 
  //upper left edge of B2 to upper left edge of E4.
  ClientAnchor anchor1 = helper.createClientAnchor();
  anchor1.setCol1(1);
  anchor1.setRow1(1); 
  anchor1.setCol2(4);
  anchor1.setRow2(3);

  //Anchor2
  //This determines the size of the shape to be from 
  //upper left edge of F2 to upper left edge of I4.
  ClientAnchor anchor2 = helper.createClientAnchor();
  anchor2.setCol1(5);
  anchor2.setRow1(1); 
  anchor2.setCol2(8);
  anchor2.setRow2(3);

  //From here on XSSF only.
  if (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
   XSSFDrawing xssfDrawing = (XSSFDrawing)drawing;
   //This is the default. Right arrow.
   XSSFClientAnchor xssfAnchor = (XSSFClientAnchor)anchor1;
   XSSFSimpleShape xssfShape = xssfDrawing.createSimpleShape(xssfAnchor);
   xssfShape.setShapeType(ShapeTypes.HOME_PLATE);
   xssfShape.setLineWidth(1);
   xssfShape.setLineStyle(0);
   xssfShape.setLineStyleColor(0, 0, 0);

   //This is the default. Right arrow again.
   xssfAnchor = (XSSFClientAnchor)anchor2;
   xssfShape = xssfDrawing.createSimpleShape(xssfAnchor);
   xssfShape.setShapeType(ShapeTypes.HOME_PLATE);
   xssfShape.setLineWidth(1);
   xssfShape.setLineStyle(0);
   xssfShape.setLineStyleColor(0, 0, 0);
   //Now flip this horizontally. -> Left arrow.
   xssfShape.getCTShape().getSpPr().getXfrm().setFlipH(true);
  }

  //From here on HSSF only.
  if (workbook instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {
   HSSFPatriarch hssfDrawing = (HSSFPatriarch)drawing;

   //This is the default. Right arrow.
   HSSFClientAnchor hssfAnchor = (HSSFClientAnchor)anchor1;
   HSSFSimpleShape hssfShape = hssfDrawing.createSimpleShape(hssfAnchor);
   hssfShape.setShapeType(HSSFShapeTypes.HomePlate);
   hssfShape.setLineWidth(1);
   hssfShape.setLineStyle(0);
   hssfShape.setLineStyleColor(0, 0, 0);

   //This is the default. Right arrow again.
   hssfAnchor = (HSSFClientAnchor)anchor2;
   hssfShape = hssfDrawing.createSimpleShape(hssfAnchor);
   hssfShape.setShapeType(HSSFShapeTypes.HomePlate);
   hssfShape.setLineWidth(1);
   hssfShape.setLineStyle(0);
   hssfShape.setLineStyleColor(0, 0, 0);
   //Now flip this horizontally. -> Left arrow.
   hssfShape.setFlipHorizontal(true);
  }


  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

It produces:

[image]